# Copy data from DB1 to DB2 in Oracle 11g using a database_link

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have one test database called ADVNXT and a Production called Prod
I have data in ADVNXT that I need to move to production. I was told that I can access the data in ADVNXT from Production env this way:

```
select * from gl_newfeed_bio@ADVNXT_LINK
```

Since I only need to move certain data from ADVNXT to Production, I should do:
In my Production env. I should type in:

```
 select * from mytable1@ADVNXT_LINK
 where Inst = 'CC'
 and submitYr = '1505'
```

By running the above script I can see all of the 400 records that are in ADVNXT from my SQL Developer Production environtment.

But what I need is to Get this 400 record from ADVNXT and inserted into the exact same table (mytable1) in Production. I tried the following and does not work:

```
  select * from mytable1@ADVNXT_LINK
  where Inst = 'CC'
  and submitYr = '1505'
  INSERT INTO mytable1
```

I'm afraid to do :

```
 insert into mytable1@ADVNXT_LINK
 select * from mytable1
 where Inst = 'CC'
 and SubmitYr = '1505'
```

because running this script in Production means inserting into ADVNXT  instead of Production database, am I correct?

Comment: I don't understand "uisn" in the title, can you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

After reading a lot I finally try the following and it is working:
In Production environment I run:

```
Insert into mytable1
select * from mytable1@ADVNEXT_LINK
where Inst = 'CC'
and SubmitYr = '1505'
```